# Usernames in route with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I'm struggling to get usernames to show in the routes related to devise.

How do I get the following routes to show?

www.blabla.com/username/edit
www.blabla.com/username/event/id

Do I have to declare a scope within a scope? Thanks for the help.

Right now my routes file looks like this

```
Weplanthings::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :vendors

  resources :venues

  resources :events

  get "profiles/index"

  get "users/index"

  get "users/show"
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'events#index', as: :tag

   authenticated :user do
     root :to => 'home#index'
   end
   match '/event/new', :to => 'events#new'
   root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    match '/login', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    match '/logout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get "/edit" => "devise/sessions#edit"
    match '/edit', :to => 'devise/sessions#edit'
    scope ":username", :as => "user" do
      #resources :users
      match '/', :to => 'profiles#index'
      match '/edit', :to => 'devise/sessions#edit'
      match '/event/:id', :to => 'events#show'

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is for you to use the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

It will make much easier to do what you want and just with a single line of code.